# Ошибка Gradle при запуске нового проекта Android studio

Tags: android, gradle

Всем привет. До этого работал в студии под `win7`, всё было нормально. Вчера поставил `Xubuntu`, установил `Android studio`, `sdk` и `jdk 1.8`. Создал новый проект и получил вот это: `Error:Process 'command '/opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2.`

В логах пишет это:

> 12.13.32 Gradle sync started
>
> 12.13.32 Gradle sync failed: Process 'command '/opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value
>   2
>            Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Читал тему на `stackoverflow`, но там совсем другая проблема, как я понял, т.к. никаких библиотек я не добавлял. Чистая студия с пустым проектом. Подскажите, что можно сделать?

Версия `gradle 2.2.2`.

UPD: Пробовал сменить владельца файла `/opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java`, на который ругается (принадлежал root), не помогло. `multidex` в `gradle.build` прописан.

UPD2: Исправил эту проблему указав в настройках путь до нужной версии jdk, но теперь возникла новая. Либо зависает при открытии проекта на `gradle build running` и выдаёт в консоли gradle кучу ошибок, либо нормально открывает проект, но подчёркивает красным R. `Rebuild project` не помогает.

В консоли ругается на какие-то потоки и вот это пишет:

> AAPT err(Facade for 20121472): /home/javir/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.1/aapt: 3: /home/javir/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.1/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Comment: Что показывает: $ gradle --version ?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то код 2 означает ошибку доступа к файлу. Предположения: нужного файла нет на месте или к нему нет доступа под текущим пользователем

Comment: Ну либо нет доступа на создание / запись файла под текущим пользователем

Comment: И что показывают логи IDE (Help | Show Log) ?

Comment: @lospejos gradle --version показало, что gradle не установлен. Установил его, не помогло. Тыкнул в настройках галочку на use default gradle wrapper, тоже не помогло. Логи вставлю в вопрос.

Comment: Логи все выложить? Их очень много.

Comment: Пятый день уже не могу Андроид студию запустить, помогите кто-нибудь

Comment: Нашёл в логах это: **Process 'command '/opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2**. Проверил этот файл, принадлежит пользователю root и доступ к нему, как я понял, ограничен для других пользвателей: **rwxr-xr-x**. Это может быть причиной ошибки и как можно исправить?